# Echo a string with variable inside, getted from DB

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, variables, echo

I get from a MySQL query a string and I've to print it to screen. Into this string, I need to print some variable too. The string from DB could be:

```
Finally, the team {$matchData['team_name']} have scored a point!
```

`$matchData['team_name']` is an array used during the calculation of the match, and if I do a simple

```
echo $matchData['team_name'];
```

will print the correct name of the team (BOSTON in this case). But why if I echo the string getted from DB, `echo print:`

```
Finally, the team {$matchData['team_name']} have scored a point!
```

and not

```
Finally, the team BOSTON have scored a point!
```

**Where I fail?**

Comment: Can you show us how you are echoing the string please?  How is the variable passed etc.

Comment: I get the string from the DB and I put it into a variable $textToPrint. After I do an echo as echo $testToPrint;

Comment: `{$var}` inside a string is not interpreted as a variable unless its hardcoded in PHP code surrounded by double-quotes. If its coming from a db or file, etc., it doesn't work like that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... What is your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

PHP seems to handle variable substitution in strings only in the simpler cases... the foolproof way to make sure it always works is to use concatenation, like:

```
echo "Finally, the team ".$matchData['team_name']." have scored a point!";
```

The PHP man page does give this example though:

```
// You can also use arrays
$baz = array("value" => "foo");

echo "this is {$baz['value']} !"; // this is foo !
```

So you might want to double check your syntax against that, too.

Finally, echo takes a parameter list of variable length so you can also write:

```
echo "Finally, the team ", $matchData['team_name'], " have scored a point!";
```

Answer (score -1):

Variable substitution in strings works in only exactly one case: in string literals in source code:

```
$foo = 'bar';
$baz = "This $foo works";
```

It does **not** work on any random input you get from anywhere else. Imagine what would happen if a user typed this into your webpage:

> Hi, this is my $password.

If PHP would simply substitute `$password` for the variable of the same name, it'd be trivial to snoop out a program's internals. That's not the way it works.

The best thing for you to do is to explicitly leave placeholders in your database data and explicitly substitute them with explicitly defined data. E.g.:

```
$string = 'Finally, the team %s have scored a point!';
$team   = 'Foos';

printf($string, $team);
```

http://php.net/sprintf