# using variables stored in mysql text

Tags: php, mysql

i have a situation where i need to be able to store variables from mysql. the pages i am creating are dynamic and contain different user data, what im chasing is the following

```
//stored in user database
$firstname = "BOB"
$lastname = "MARLEY"

//how i want th content from a mysql database to display in html
hello my name is BOB MARLEY

//how it displays at the moment
hello my name is $firstname $lastname
```

i cant seem to work it out at all

this is my current database code

```
<?php
        $firstname= "BOB";
        $lastnamename= "marley";
    $get_content= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_forms_content WHERE forms_content_formid='1' LIMIT 1 ");
    while($found_content = mysqli_fetch_array($get_content))
    { 
        echo $found_content['forms_content_content'];
    }   
?>
```

any help is greatly apreciated

Comment: You should use a template system.

Comment: for a start it should be `$found_content['firstname']` assuming thats already in the db?

Comment: Where do you connect to the database?

Comment: Why do you set firstname and lastnamename in the while  loop rather than using the db results?

Comment: @Dagon I think the `forms_content_content` column contains a string that includes variable references, he wants those variables to be substituted.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27516571/476 (No idea why it's at -1 at the moment, if someone could upvote any of those answers over there we could close this as duplicate.)

Comment: could be, its not a very clear question.

Comment: Are you sure the database has the correct info?

Comment: It's very clear, since he showed the output from echoing the database columns.

Comment: but why is the name hard coded in the loop then?

Comment: And, what does var_dump $found_content say?

Comment: sorry i didnt proof read the code before i posted here i have changed and moved it out of the loop and for the exercise i have removed the DB connect code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right solution is to use a template library. To do what you're trying, you need to use `eval`:

```
$firstname= "BOB";
$lastname= "marley";
while($found_content = mysqli_fetch_array($get_content))
{ 
    eval ('echo "' . $found_content['forms_content_content'] . '";');
}
```

This is very dangerous. If the database contains values that can be set by the user, they could execute any PHP code from it.

Comment: I don't think `eval` can be used without `()`. Though it would look a lot better.

Comment: It needed a semicolon in the argument to `eval()`, try it now.

Comment: yep thats working now, :-) obviously this isnt really recommend but this is for some dynamic pdf forms, is there any other solutions to get the same result

Comment: *firstname* db field, *lastname* db field

Comment: when running this in php works fine when running inside fpdf it just executes and doesnt display the pdf document just html

Comment: I guess you need to assign a variable and put that into the PDF, instead of echoing. So change `echo` to `$var =`.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to str_replace them out;

```
echo str_replace(array('$firstname', '$lastname'), array($firstname, $lastname), $found_content['forms_content_content']);
```

Can see a working example here; http://codepad.org/xFEowbMZ

Comment: Way better solution than using `eval()` +1